# Using dictionary in pandas to use as condition

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to use dictionary as a condition to create a new column. I have big click stream data set. I have dictionary For example:

```
Domain   keyword  
Audi        a4
VW          golf
BMW         2er
```

I want to use dictionary key as first condition and value as second condition. How it will be possible because i need to check dictionary "value" in URL column.

I can do manually by this:

```
df_filtered = df[(df['domain'] == 'bmw') & (df['url].str.contains('2er'))
```

but how i can also define third column based on that condition. For example when condition fulfilled for bmw then "2er"

Comment: Do you want to use a dataframe or a dict?

Comment: I have a data frame of click-stream. I want to create new column  with the help of dictionary which will fulfill 2 conditions as mentioned earlier

Comment: Seems you are looking for `np.select`.